# Jenkins / Maven: Could not resolve default JAVA_HOME path, Build failing

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I've got a problem regarding Java Builds in Jenkins.

The Error I resolve is the following one:

`Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Jenkins\jre\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.`

I got `JDK1.6` and `JDK1.7` projects, so I need two JDK installations. For my default Java JDK I used the 1.6 for the `JAVA_HOME` variable, which points to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`. Same for the 1.7 version, but in a separated variable (`JAVA_HOME7`).
The `PATH` variable contains the appended `\bin` to the two  JDK versions.

In Jenkins I also added both versions for JDK and as helper variables.
If I am setting a concrete version for a project (e.g. `JDK1.7`), then it's building without any issues. Unfortunately I've got a lot of build-projects, so it would be time consuming to set this manually.

I don't understand where the call or variable for the path of the error `C:\Jenkins\jre\..\lib\tools.jar` is set and where I can modify it...

Jenkins Version: 1.509.4

Any hints or advices how to solve this problem?

Comment: You say you set the JAVE_HOME variable.  Is this a typo in just your post or did you really?  (It should be JAVA_HOME)

Comment: typo, sorry... fixed it in the original post

Comment: This could be a rights issue. Make sure `JAVA_HOME` is either set system wide or for the user that runs Jenkins. It might be that you only set it for your current user which doesn't run Jenkins.

Comment: In Jenkins configuration you could register both of your jdk. Then in specific build in java options select one of them. JAVA_HOME is used only in default java configuration.

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same problem. The below steps solved the problem

1) Go to Manage Jenkins - Configure system

2) Add JAVA_HOME and its path in Global Properties - Environment Variables

3) Add JDK and path in JDK section

Comment: In Jenkins 1.575, when you do step #3 *(add the JDK)* it prompts you for the `JAVA_HOME` path, so you can actually skip step #2 *(skip adding it under Global Properties - Environment Variables)*... step 3 was the ticket, thanks!