# Maven uses an incorrect Java version when it is executed by Jenkins

Tags: java, linux, maven, jenkins

I have some projects compiled and deployed with Maven and Jenkins and they have worked fine until now that I have changed the java version from 6 to 7.

In order to do this I executed the command *sudo update-alternatives --config javac* and changed the values of JAVA_HOME and PATH in the */etc/profile* file. I have also modified the pom file so it uses jdk 1.7:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I execute them on the console they compile fine and the displayed version is correct:

```
javac -version
javac 1.7.0_55

mvn install -debug
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.7.0_55
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

However, when I do the same in a jenkins job, Maven uses the 1.6 version instead of 1.7:

```
javac -version
javac 1.7.0_55

mvn install -debug
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.6.0_31
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

I have also modified the maven configuration file that I use to indicate the new version, and in the Jenkins administration panel I have changed the JDK version. However, Maven is still using the 1.6 jdk.

Do you know how can I change it?

Comment: You can override the global JDK for each Jenkins job - perhaps that's your issue?

Comment: I have just found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270002/jenkins-maven-could-not-resolve-default-java-home-path-build-failing?rq=1). What I had to do was to define the JAVA_HOME also in the global configuration of Jenkins. Thanks Anders!

Comment: Maybe you could post it as your own answer, some people doesn't care to read this comments sometimes.

Comment: The steps are:   1) Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure system
   2) Add JAVA_HOME and its path in Global Properties -> Environment Variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270002/jenkins-maven-could-not-resolve-default-java-home-path-build-failing?rq=1). 
It is necessary to define the JAVA_HOME variable also in the global configuration of Jenkins. 
As Sudharsan explained, the steps are:

1. Go to Manage Jenkins - Configure system
2. Add JAVA_HOME and its path in Global Properties - Environment Variables

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem when changing Jenkins jobs from JDK 1.6 to JDK 1.8. I deleted the JDK1.6 entry from "Manage Jenkins/Configure System", leaving only JDK1.8. I expected jobs would begin using JDK1.8 but they didn't. I checked the jobs and they didn't have any JDK assignment. Restarting Jenkins didn't help either.

In the end, I noticed that by just re-Saving a job, it subsequently started using the correct JDK1.8.

(Jenkins ver. 1.602)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue was solved as I mentioned on a comment, and I also published an answer with the full explanation, but that answer was deleted by an admin.