# Compilation error in Jenkins, but not in Eclipse and command line - Same machine and JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I'm configuring a Jenkins environment at my local machine but I'm facing a very strange error. My application doesn't compile through Jenkins, but it works with Eclipse and command line (mvn install).

Well, I'm using the same JDK, same Maven, same computer, same goals!
Does anyone know the reason of this problem? 
Really thanks for the attention.

- OS: Windows 7
- Maven: 3.2.3
- Java: 1.6.0.33

Error:

```
[INFO] Compiling 213 source files to C:\Users\pimenta\.jenkins\jobs\M - Homolog\workspace\target\classes
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/constraints/Size
    at org.hibernate.validator.ap.util.ConstraintHelper.<init>(ConstraintHelper.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintAnnotationVisitor.<init>(ConstraintAnnotationVisitor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor.process(ConstraintValidationProcessor.java:101)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:624)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:553)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:698)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:981)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:554)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.constraints.Size
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    ... 53 more
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Make sure you run mvn clean in the commandline. My gut is eclipse is compiling fine but mvn would have failed just like jenkins had it been cleaned.

Comment: Run the maven command on Jenkins with "--debug" option and look for errors when trying to download "validation-api.jar".

Comment: @AdamGent my goal is already with it! "clean install -X --debug -P homolog"

Comment: @GergelyBacso I tried, but no information about the lib was showed. If it works directly in command line means that the lib is already in my repository, isn't?

Comment: Depending on your settings you could have another repository defined. I was hoping that you will find some indications of not being able to retrieve this jar.

Comment: @PimentaDev. Make the process that runs Jenkins a separate user in your operating system (make sure it has its own `.m2` folder and not yours). I have seen bizarre file issues when sharing a `.m2` local repo with concurrent processes on windows.

Comment: @GergelyBacso aaa ok! Unfortunately isn't the case... is the same repository for both

Comment: Is it still happening?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Jenkins cannot find a class (in this case `javax.validation.constraints.Size`). Perhaps Jenkins does not see your `JAVA_HOME` properly, as in the case of this question: [Jenkins / Maven: Could not resolve default JAVA_HOME path, Build failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270002/jenkins-maven-could-not-resolve-default-java-home-path-build-failing).

If so, the steps to correct (as outlined in the answer) are:

1. Go to Manage Jenkins - Configure system
2. Add JAVA_HOME and its path in Global Properties - Environment Variables
3. Add JDK and path in JDK section

Comment: It's already defined. I also confirmed it looking at the "system information" screen.