# Jenkins - Unable to run maven project in local system which is set as slave

Tags: maven, jenkins

HI I have set my local machine as Slave and created a job to run scripts whenever there is a build deployment in Client machine. Howerver, I am seeing below error trace and scripts are not running.

`[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :`
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on `a JRE rather than a JDK?`
[INFO] 1 error
`[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------`
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
`[INFO] BUILD FAILURE`
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
`[INFO] Total time: 17.874 s`
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-24T17:08:33+04:00
`[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/247M`
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project EmiratesNBD_FaceLift_Smoke: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. 
Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

I have set my MAVEN AND jAVA Set in my environment variables correctly. kindly suggest

Comment: Hi but did you add a JRE or a JDK as JAVA HOME variable? Like the stack trace said?

Comment: @Vall0n - Yes I did , added JDK (c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_77) as my Java_Home

Comment: Seems like also the naming of the env variable is import. Is it JAVA_HOME? More infos from a similiar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270002/jenkins-maven-could-not-resolve-default-java-home-path-build-failing

Comment: @Vall0n-  Yes it is JAVA_HOME.

Comment: @Aditya Consider answering your own question so that this question doesn't appear in the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the most safe way to have a correct JDK on Jenkins slave is to use `Jenkins Tools Configuration` (in case you use Jenkins 2). It's available via `Jenkins Manage` page. For versions below 2 it's available in `Configure System`

- In `Jenkins Tools Configuration` find `JDK`
- Create new JDK installation (choose `Automatic install` from java.sun.com)
- In your Maven job choose the defined JDK (in field `JDK`)

Now you have no problems with installed or not installed JDK, 32 or 64 bit and so on...

Comment: Thank you guys - I have sorted the issue. The problem is with global configuation.. my workspace is trying to use the JDK installed in Master machine and hence failing to trigger scripts. I have created another JDK installation and pointed to my local machine and scripts are running. Thanks again!